# Looping through multi-dimensional array and filtering based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I believe *similar* questions have been asked but none which deal with the problem I am facing.

I have an array of shape `(H,W,L)` - I must loop through each instance of the array to filter out values (their x,y location) that meet a particular criteria. (say  `val > t_r` and `val < t_c`) - I must repeat this for each of the K values.

For eg: If we have an array of shape (2,3,4)

```
A = [[[1,2,3,], [3,4,5,]], 
        [[6,7,8],[1,4,5]], 
        [[5,7,7],[9,4,3]],
        [[1,2,4],[4,6,7]]]
```

suppose the first criteria is `val > 2` and the second criteria is `val < 6` and store the (row, col) value in a `N x 3` array. Where the first 2 values are the `'row','col'` and the last one corresponds to the layer / third dimension. 
then the expected output of the operation should be something like -

`output = [[0,2,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,2,0]....]` this would correspond to the values filtered from `A[:,:,0]`

One approach I have thought of is - using 3 for loops - i,j,k to loop over each of the elements, but I am unable to figure out the exact implementation. I would also like to implement vectorization wherever possible. I could use some guidance.

Comment: Just a general remark: you almost never need loops with NumPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `np.nonzero` and vectorize your comparisons.

```
a = np.asarray(A)
res = np.vstack(np.nonzero((a>2)&(a<6))).T
```

---

```
array([[0, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 2],
       [3, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

You can always reorder the columns to your liking e.g.:

```
res[:, [1,2,0]]
```

---

```
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 3]], dtype=int64)
```